# (Android App/Web App) (Noob) How do I get started on making an app like this?

Tags: android, android-studio, web-applications

Ok so first off: I am a complete noob when it comes to Android app development. I used to have Android studio and wanted to make an app. I found it very confusing and hard to learn.

Second: I know HTML and CSS pretty well, but not JS or XML or any other languages.

I want to make an app that is basically a vault. When you open it, you get a login screen (with fingerprint login preferred). Then you login and are presented with a vault to store images, files, and etc.

I have no clue where to get started or what to learn. I want to learn how, but it seems very confusing to me.

I could also make this a web app so which ever is easier, let me know.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are already apps like this and if you just want to create something, than this is a really big goal. To have it fully functioning I'd give you a year if you do it on a regular basis since you never programmed before. You should start with something small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is you start with very small projects. In each one, aim to make something you haven't tried before (don't be repetitive in your apps). I suggest you make the following apps, so in each one you learn a little about what shall be useful:

- +/- Calculator
- Application which asks for a password, and if correct, sends you to a second activity
- Application which can save information even if the application is closed
- Application which can shows a series of images one below another
  (scrolling down)

This will get you a nice idea on Android Basics which will be useful for your project. If you were to jump directly into it, you would find yourself in a sea of abstract information and have no idea what to do.

Remember: small projects give you better understanding. Google and StackOverflow are your best friends